# Get current data from latest history table or from an item row?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have to store a list of history pricing data history. I use the histroy data to look over the last 28 days. I pick the highest value from the last 28 days and then compare that with the current value where the difference is the sale discount.

Our DBA says store the data in a table that has a FROM DATE and a TO DATE were a TO DATE of NULL will be the current price. However for performance reasons he also wants to store the current price in the stock items table. There will be triggers to ensures the stock item price matches the lastest price in the price history data. I don't envisage a stock item having more than 10 price changes

I can't help thinking having the current price in two location is a bad idea. However, I also do like getting the current stock price from the stock item row. We have an sql 2000 database.

Not sure what's the best approach is.

Answer (score 1):

Either approach is valid.  The deciding factor should be the overall performance impact of each solution.

Since looking up the current price probably happens much more often then updating the price, you should choose a solution that maximizes the performance of look ups.

Depending on the overall design that will most likely be the price in the actual stock item row (you are probably already getting that row for other data anyway).

The trigger that updates the price in the other table will only be execute when the price is updated and therefore the performance hit of the trigger will not affect the apps overall performance.

Also, if you are needing to lookup the high price from the past 28 days often, it may be better to have the trigger store that value in your stock item row as well.

This does lead to some data redundany but the performance benefit may well be worth it.

The key to data integrity is making sure that trigger does it's job properly.